# Using / between parts with spaces in them

Tags: punctuation

Consider this sentence:

> Development of semantic networks/ontologies could ...

Here, I mean "semantic networks" and/or "ontologies". Is the sentence Ok in its current form or it needs to be changes? (possibly adding a hyphen between semantic and networks?)

Comment: If it were me, without any further context, I would write *development of ontologies and semantic networks*. I don't like the use of the slash, nor of *and/or*. But the main point is that all you need to do is swap the position of the nouns. Since *semantic* is an adjective, there can be no confusion over the two terms if they are used in the opposite order.

Answer (score 1):

The slash without spaces is correct. I would, however, suggest avoiding the slash entirely. I second Jason Bassford's suggestions to place "ontologies" first and to use a word in place of the slash.

Comment: How? you mean using a hyphen, semantic-networks?

Comment: @Shayan "of ontologies and semantic networks" no hyphen is needed.